# Calculate Sum based on condition

Tags: sum, abap

How to do summation in the internal table with condition?

For example, my itab have the following data:

```
itab l_bcode_i :

vgpos[1] :10 , menge[1]:600

vgpos[2] :10 , menge[2]:500

vgpos[3] :20 , menge[3]:400

vgpos[4] :20 , menge[4]:300

vgpos[5] :30 , menge[5]:200

vgpos[6] :30 , menge[6]:10
```

The requirement request to sum up the data with the same vgpos number by using the menge, and use to display another message.

I try to show

```
vgpos: 10 menge = 1100

vgpos:20 menge = 500

vgpos:30 menge = 210
```

I try to use loop and sum, however the result not as the result I need because it will total up all the menge value by ignored the where clause condition that I set. Any recommendation or suggestion is appreciated:

at last, it should menge = 1810

```
LOOP AT LT_BCODE_I INTO LT_BCODE_I WHERE VGPOS = LW_LIPS2-VGPOS.
        AT LAST.
          SUM.
          cl_demo_output=>display( LT_BCODE_I-MENGE ).
        ENDAT.
      ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I able to fixed my problem by using the following code:

In stead of At Last, I change to use the AT END. After used the AT END, I able to get the result I need.

```
LOOP AT LT_BCODE_I INTO LT_BCODE_I WHERE VGBEL = LT_LIPS-VGBEL AND VGPOS = LT_LIPS-VGPOS.
        AT END OF VGBEL.
          SUM.
          LT_BCODE_I-MENGE = LT_BCODE_I-MENGE .
        ENDAT.
      ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: and what about the material name ? it will keep showing 2 row with the same name of material with summed qty, am i right ?  can u tell me how did u handle that  so we can displaying 1 material with summed qty ,

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` statement calculates the sum of Numeric Components(Numeric data types). Check and validate the data type for the field `MENGE`.
Read the documentation about [SUM statement](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapsum.htm),

Also, there is the condition on the `LOOP`. So, loop executes only once, if VGPOS is considered as key.

Comment: do have other solution to do this?

Comment: You can use COLLECT to calculate summation on internal table.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples in the documentation of [SUM](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsum.htm).

Here is an excerpt for *"Calculation of a sum with SUM at AT END OF. The lines of the respective current group level are evaluated"*:

```
DATA:
  BEGIN OF wa,
    col1 TYPE i,
    col2 TYPE i,
  END OF wa,
  itab LIKE TABLE OF wa WITH EMPTY KEY.

itab = VALUE #( FOR i = 1 UNTIL i > 5
                FOR j = 1 UNTIL j > i
                ( col1 = i col2 = j ) ).

LOOP AT itab INTO wa.
  AT END OF col1.
    SUM.
    cl_demo_output=>write( wa ).
  ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
cl_demo_output=>display( wa ).
```